# PHP Detect parent image user url

Tags: php, gd, parent

I have a php file that outputs a image with dynamic content.
I need to get the url of the img using it. Example: `www.bla.com/`

```
<img src="signature.php?color=black">
```

The php would return `www.bla.com/` 
Can I do this **WITHOUT** using GET vars and php on the img page?

Comment: Where is bla.com being returned?

Comment: So in the signature.php file I could just get the value by accessing a variable. @Terminus

Comment: So you want to check the HTTP_REFERER? Try the php $_SERVER variable. `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]`

Comment: It seems like it works, but how reliable is is? Could someone edit that variable

Comment: You should definitely look up how the `$_SERVER` variable works. Good read. You'll probably find something on php.net. it's just too long to explain here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Terminus for helping, my solution was to use:

```
$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]
```

Then do some sanitizing just in case.